# Installing Applications from Store in Windows 8.1 Without MS Account

Tags: windows-store

How can one install applications from Windows Store in Windows 8.1 without MS account?

When I try to install an app it asks for the local user password then asks to login using a MS account or create a new account or cancel.

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a work around for this?

Nope.

If you want to use their store, you have to have an account with them.

From MS's Apps store tutorial "[Getting apps for your PC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-8/apps-windows-store-tutorial)":

> You need to be connected to the Internet to open the Store and you’ll need to sign in using a Microsoft account.

This does NOT mean you need to be logged into Windows with an MS account.

If you are, then it will just let you into the store; if your signed in with a local or domain account, then the store will ask you for a valid MS account to log into the store with, when you try to access it.

Comment: An application like Skype will appear to require a Microsoft Account in order to install it but in the case of Skype its possible to manually log into the account. As you point out, you don't have to link your local account to that Microsoft account, to download the applications, except in rare situation like OneDrive where it actually is a requirement.  The option to skip the step is not always easy to find.

Comment: @Ramhound While I agree, I'm not sure what that has to do with accessing the App Store?

Comment: Because of that one application is Skype it might explain the author's question?